# Best way to implement a home button on multiple toolbars when using storyboarding

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

I have an app with many views, each with their own toolbar.  I want to implement a home button on each, but i'm wondering if it is wise to have a bunch of segues going back to the first view controller.  Is there a better way to implement this?.

Answer (score 0):

If efficiency is your game, house the button in it's own UIView and overlay that UIView over your UIViewController at launch.  Then it's a matter of setting alpha (and position if that's also your game) to 0.0 or 1.0 at the right times.